# How can I create a new variable from answers that come from two different variables?

Tags: regression, spss

I have two variables: RACE & HISPANIC

- RACE has 5 responses 1-White 2-Black/AA 3-Asian etc.
- I am interested in those that answered 'White'
- HISPANIC has 13 responses 0-11=Hispanic countries 12-Not Hispanic
- I am interested in those that answered 'Yes' in 00 to 11

I am looking to create a new variable ETHNICITY made up of those that 1-White and those that answered 00-11-Hispanic. I am predicting heart disease rates(dependent) among three other variables, ETHNICITY is the only one where the answers come from two different variables. I am using SPSS, binary logistic regression.

Do I

- First, compute a new variable for each White=1 and another for HISPANIC=00-11?
- Second, do I then create a new variable to merge the two? How do I do that? I've had trouble doing the compute If,

Comment: Welcome to Stats.SE. Can you please [edit] your post and say which software are you using? By the way, take the opportunity to take the [Tour], if you haven't done it already. See also some tips on [ask], on [formatting help](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and on writing down equations using [LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Comment: You can combine Race and Ethnicity into one demographic variable if you want, but the original labels are correct.  White/Black/etc. refers to race;  Hispanic/Non-hispanic refers to ethnicity.  White-hispanic is not an ethnicity per se....  A better approach is to include Race, Ethnicity, and the interaction of Race and Ethnicity in the model.  If the interaction is significant or meaningful, then it makes sense to break out e.g. white-hispanic vs. black-hispanic.  Otherwise, maybe not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you're using SPSS, you can compute a new variable using the syntax or the menu commands in the following way:

```
COMPUTE white_hispanic = ( (race = 1) & (hispanic <= 11) ) .
EXECUTE .
```

`Race = 1` corresponds to the `white` category and that `hispanic <= 11` corresponds to the categories to be considered.

The ampersand `&` corresponds to the **and** operator. So, the above expression reads as:
The new variabe `white_hispanic` is `1` (i.e., truth for SPSS), when the `race` variable is equal to `0` and when the `hispanic` variable is equal to `1`. If one of those variables, or both, is not equal to their respective values, then the `white_hispanic` assumes the value `0` (i.e., false for SPSS).

---

**Edit:**

If you also want to compare "non-Hispanic whites" vs "Hispanics", then you can use:

```
DO IF ( (race = 1) & (hispanic = 12) ) .
COMPUTE nonHispanicWhite_vs_Hispanic = 0 .
ELSE IF (hispanic <= 11) .
COMPUTE nonHispanicWhite_vs_Hispanic = 1 .
ELSE .
COMPUTE nonHispanicWhite_vs_Hispanic = $SYSMIS .
END IF.
EXECUTE .
```

If the individual is "non-hispanic & white", this code attributes the value `0`; if the individual is "hispanic" the value will be `1`; otherwise the value will be the system missing value.

---

By the way, let me point out that I agree with the line of thought of [Sal Mangiafico](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/166526). In particular, when doing a logistic regression, you may have several independent variables (covariates).

So, you may add both `race` and `hispanic` to the binary logistic regression model, both defined as categorical, and perhaps considering the first category of each as the reference category.

This approach do not requires the creation of new variables, and you may even include the interaction term `race*hispanic` if you wish to consider the possibility of having different effects of `race` among distinct values of `hispanic`.

If there are a small number of cases, at least for some of the categories, you may create two new variables, `white` and `hisp`, to be used in the logistic regression, and defined as follows:

```
COMPUTE white = (race = 1) .
COMPUTE hisp = (hispanic <= 11) .
EXECUTE .
```

Of course you may use different subsets of the possible values for the new variables, that may have more than 2 categories.

However, although reducing the number of categories of each variable may be appealing, caution should be taken, since we may be reducing the [statistical power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_(statistics)) of the logistic regression.

Comment: @ElleMadrid I've edited my answer, to adjust it to your edit.

Comment: thanks so much, the syntax worked. I extracted the values and created two separate variables: White and Hispanic.
I now need to combine the two to run binary 0,1 non-Hispanic White, Hispanic.

Comment: @ElleMadrid I'm not sure I understand what you need. `white_hispanic` is one variable with two categories. Do you need more variables or more categories or something else?

Comment: So sorry it is not very clear. I need to merge the two newly created variables from my syntax. I ended up with two, which works if I can merge them and assign different categories once combined in one variable.

Comment: Do you mean something like: ```COMPUTE white_nonhispanic = ~( (race = 1) & (hispanic = 12) ) . ```? This would attribute `0` to individuals that are white and non-hispanic and `1` to all others ("non-whites" and/or "non-hispanic"). The tilde `~` negates the result (turns "true" into "false" and vice-versa).

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I've been looking for. I just ran it and it captured "0' non-whites/non-Hispanic correctly, but the frequency for 1=("non-whites" and/or "non-hispanic") does not capture the number of Hispanics.
I believe I can fix this if I can merge the newly created "white_nonhispanic" (0) with a previous syntax I ran "hispan_only" (1) which captured Hispanics only. Can I run a syntax to join the two?

Comment: From the 2 variables, it seems to me that you are focusing on 4 possibilities: "white & hispanic"; "white & non-hispanic"; "non-white & hispanic"; and "non-white & non-hispanic". Do you want a variable that has 1 of these 4 possibilities set to 1 (or 0) and the other 3 possibilities set to 0 (or 1)? Which case do you need?

Comment: Each of the 2 variables has 2 possibilities 0,1 and 0,1. I need to pull 1 possibility from each (0) "White & non-Hispanic" from "white_nonhispanic" and (1) from "hispanic". I ultimately need a new variable with two possibilities non-Hispanic Whites and Hispanics.

Comment: And what about the people that is  "non-white & non-hispanic", in which category should they belong to? Or should they not be considered in your analysis?

Comment: They will not be analyzed. I am only analyzing non-Hispanic Whites and Hispanics.

Comment: @ElleMadrid I've updated my answer. Please let me know if there is some clarification you need.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH! This absolutely solved my data issue. I can now run my test.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in Excel quite easily:

Filter the two variables Race and Hispanic so to show only "white" (condition1) for the former and "yes" (condition2) for the latter. Then,  add a column where you input 1 for the rows where conditions 1 and 2 are met and 0 in all other cases. Using the function "filter" allows you to "play" with data quite easily. Otherwise you can use a formula using the functions if and or. You set the conditions you want so the new variable will incorporate the information you need.

I guess you want a dummy variable that takes value 1 for white and hispanic and 0 for all the other cases: am I correct?

Comment: hi @abb, yes I need a dummy variable for all 1 values-White and a second value for all 00-11 values in the second variable Hispanic. I can extract the values from the variables by recoding, but I have difficulty, merging the two. I'm working in SPSS.